# Invoke-Sqlcmd could not load file or assembly 'system.compiler.runtimeservice.unsafe'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've installed the SQL Server powershell module using the below commands:

```
Install-PackageProvider -Name NuGet -MinimumVersion 2.8.5.201 -Force
Install-Module -Name "SqlServer" -AllowClobber -Force
```

I created an image of this VM and launched another VM using the image.

I have a script that runs automatically when the newly launched VM comes up.
The script has the below code:

```
Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance {{vmName}}\{{instanceName}} -InputFile {{sqlPath}} -TrustServerCertificate
```

Sometimes it works, but sometimes it gives the below error:

```
SqlServer\Invoke-Sqlcmd : Could not load file or assembly 
'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file 
specified.
```

What is the reason for this?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: So is there a `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll` on the system? Is it (specifically version 4.0.4.1 of it) registered in the GAC?